# Firebug: Track what script or line of code, which made changes

Tags: javascript, firebug

Is it possible to track what script or what line of code, that ex. set a width on an element?

//KennethBL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On IE you can use the onpropertychanged event to fire an event when the width element is fired.

On IE 9, Chrome and FF you can use the DOMAttrModified:

```
var elm = document.getElementById ("targetElemntId");
if (elm.addEventListener) { // all browsers except IE before version 9
  elm.addEventListener ('DOMAttrModified', checkProperty, false); //FF, Opera, IE
}
if (elm.attachEvent) {  // IE & Opera
  elm.attachEvent ('onpropertychange', checkProperty); // IE


 }


function checkProperty(event) {
   var name = event.attrName ? event.attrName : event.propertyName;
   if(name == "width") {
      alert("width changed");
   }
}
```

Don't know how you would achieve this on chrome though.